# Git - unable to update submodule detached HEAD on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I've noticed that on my GitHub repo, I have the submodule pointing to its first commit sha1, e.g., `aaaaaaa`.

Okay, I clone it recursively:

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/etc`

If I `cd` to submodule's dir at this moment, Git indicates that I'm in `aaaaaaa` commit.

Then, I update the submodule (returning to parent dir):

`git submodule update --remote`

If I go again to submodule's dir, the HEAD is updated, pointing to latest commit sha1, e.g., `bbbbbbb`.

But I can't reflect this change on the GitHub repository. I've tried amending the commit, forcing push, with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point here is that, with submodules, you're working with two or more git repositories, where the submodules are almost independent from the "main" module.

That "main" module has not only a reference to its submodules, it has a reference to a commit —and to a branch— as well.

After updating a submodule, you have to tell the "main" module that from now on you want it to reference that new commit.

So, the last step you have to do is:

```
cd $MainRepoPath
git add $SubmodulePath
git commit
git push $remote $branch
```

Comment: Ah, so I have to add the whole submodule. Thank you so much.